# How to remove everything within brackets for every row in a column using dplyr stringr

Tags: r, regex, tidyverse, stringr

I have the following data frame:

```r
library(tidyverse)
dat <- tribble(
  ~x, ~y,
  1,  "foo",
  2,  "bar (103 xxx)",
  3,  "bar",
  4,  "foo (yyy)"
)

dat 
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       x             y
#>   <dbl>         <chr>
#> 1     1           foo
#> 2     2 bar (103 xxx)
#> 3     3           bar
#> 4     4     foo (yyy)
```

What I want to do is to clean column `y` by removing all strings that is contained in `()` bracket. Resulting in:

```r
      x             y
  <dbl>         <chr>
1     1           foo
2     2           bar 
3     3           bar
4     4           foo
```

How can I do it?

I tried this with error:

```r
> dat  %>% stringr::str_replace(y, "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)","")
Error in stringr::str_replace(., y, "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)", "") : 
  unused argument ("")
```

Comment: It's just a syntax error. Have you tried double escaping with ```\\```?

Comment: @CAustin Tried that. Still error.

Comment: Ok, but it's a different error. Have you tried operating on this new information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the pipe `%>%`, which passes `dat` to `str_replace` as first argument, i.e. the `dot` in the error message, which is not what `str_replace` is expecting:

> ```
> > Error in stringr::str_replace(., y, "\\([a-zA-Z0-9]+\\)", "") :
>  #                              ^   dat passed here
> ```

You can use `str_replace` with `mutate` to create a new column:

```
dat %>% mutate(y = trimws(str_replace(y, "\\(.*?\\)", "")))

# A tibble: 4 x 2
#      x     y
#  <dbl> <chr>
#1     1   foo
#2     2   bar
#3     3   bar
#4     4   foo
```

---

If you want to apply `str_replace` directly after the `pipe`, you can only modify a column/vector:

```
# here use pull to extract the column and manipulate it
dat %>% pull(y) %>% str_replace("\\(.*?\\)", "") %>% trimws()
# [1] "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo"
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that these are the patterns, a `base R` option would be

```
dat$y<- sub("\\s*\\(.*", "", dat$y)
dat$y
#[1] "foo" "bar" "bar" "foo"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also just do the following, which avoids dealing with brackets:

```
library(stringr)
dat %>%
  mutate(y = str_extract(y, "^\\w+"))
```

but I'm not sure if your actual dataset is structured like that.